# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < , in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to render html page in NodeJS. When I refresh the browser I am getting this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

If I am giving the CDN path, then its not showing error.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"><br>
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="jq.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

NodeJs code - main.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/html'});
fs.readFile('index.html',function(err,data){
    if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write('File Not Found');
    } else {
        res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
});
}).listen(8800);
```

Comment: Its because a javascript file is being loaded as HTML. You need to ensure that the JS file is being loaded properly. For this, you may need to revisit your NodeJS routing.

Comment: Look in the network tab of the debugger and see what script.js or jq.js look like when they are loaded.  One of them probably is not what it should be.

Comment: You are trying to load a file that doesn't exist, you are getting your 404 page as the javascript file.

Comment: @jfriend00 it should showing `content-type:application/javascript`
 but i am getting `content-type:application/HTML`.

Comment: @TahaPaksu no i am not getting 404 error

Comment: Yes you are not getting any 404 errors, but the script source loads your 404 page. Please look at the network tab on your chrome developer tools page, and navigate to jq.js or script.js file, and look at the response.

Comment: @TahaPaksu thats what i said in above comment 
it should showing `content-type:application/javascript` but i am getting `content-type:application/HTML`

Comment: Did you look at the actual content for those files in the network tab?  The error you get sounds to me like the browser is trying to parse a Javascript file, but it's finding an HTML file and thus the script parser chokes on the first `<`.

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya please look at what I've said, you'll understand that I'm right. BTW your 404 page is `content-type:application/HTML'. You're just making me repeat myself.

Comment: @TahaPaksu - The problem you're describing does NOT cause the error the OP reports.  It may also be wrong, but that's not what causes this specific error.  This error happens when the browser thinks the file is a script file, but the content is actually HTML.  So, look at what the content is for your two `<script>` files.

Comment: @TahaPaksu you are right but i am looking for solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 we are telling the same thing.

Comment: The solution is to check that non existent script or wrong path, and fix it. Maybe it's your webserver that prevents access to that.

Comment: You all right i also know the problem but what can be the solution for this?

Comment: Please show your server code for sending your script files.  Where are the routes for those?

Comment: @jfriend00 i already added the code that i am using

Comment: Then, part of the problem is that you have no routes defined for either `/script.js` or `/jq.js` and that you're making every single file be `text/html`.  Do you understand that a node.js web server serves NO files by default.

Comment: @jfriend00 both are in the same directoty

Comment: A node.js webserver serves NO files by default.  You must have a handler for every file you wish it to send.

Comment: @jfriend00 ohk thank you

Comment: Yeah, the problem is caused because you're serving index.html and text/html for every single request.  So, when the browser asks for `/script.js`, your serving is sending it `index.html` and `text/html`.

Comment: Other dup references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656224/cant-load-local-files-when-using-nodejs-server/41656335#41656335, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935158/nodejs-expressjs-redirect-does-not-work/38935190#38935190, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505215/resources-not-loading-in-express/34506377#34506377

Comment: @jfriend00 without express solution won't be possible ?

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya - You can hand code it without Express by looking at `req.url` of every incoming http request and using a switch statement to branch based on which path has been requested, but it's kind of waste of coding time not to use what Express gives you.   You will have fewer lines of code and fewer bugs and more features and will finish your code sooner if you use Express.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have to do it without express now and then i will do with express. Thank you